# Weyl Character Formula to find $M_\lambda(\mu)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In Lie algebra book by Humphreys, he has used Weyl Character Formula to find the dimension of $V(\lambda)$ in the examples followed by the proof of this formula. But how to find the dimensions of the weight spaces $M_\lambda(\mu)$ using the Weyl character formula?

There are other formulas to find the dimension of the weight spaces, but I want to do it using the Weyl Character Formula.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean how to extract a specific coefficient from the formula? Because those multiplicities are precisely what the formula tells you.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft ya. I want to extract the coefficients of $ch_\lambda$. but I dont know how to do that. can you give me some hints

Comment: I don't know that much about how one might go about doing this in general. In type $A$, this is all governed by symmetric functions, and I think it should be possible to do something fairly nice, though there are a few things to be careful about.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft can you tell me the role of symmetric function  and  this context little bit more clearly please?

Comment: In type $A$, the character given by Weyl's character formula is a polynomial which is invariant under the action of the Weyl group, which precisely means that it is a symmetric polynomial. More precisely, it is the Schur-function corresponding to the highest weight. For more information you can check out the appendix to Fulton and Harris' Representation Theory, or Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics vol 2 (there is a chapter on symmetric functions).